# C: casting to new structure vs casting to defined structure

Tags: pointers, data-structures, struct, casting, typedef

my question is simple, does this

```
typedef struct {a;b;c;d;}bar;
((bar*)ANOTHERSTRUCTPOINTER)->a=1;
((bar*)ANOTHERSTRUCTPOINTER2)->a=1;
//<...>
((bar*)ANOTHERSTRUCTPOINTERn)->a=1;
```

has the same execution time as this?

```
((struct {a;b;c;d;}*)ANOTHERSTRUCTPOINTER)->a=1;
((struct {a;b;c;d;}*)ANOTHERSTRUCTPOINTER2)->a=1;
//<...>
((struct {a;b;c;d;}*)ANOTHERSTRUCTPOINTERn)->a=1;
```

please mind that this is just an example, so don't just question the fact i didn't use an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they mean the same thing and should compile into the same executable code.

Comment: What i know is that they do the same thing, but i'm still in doubt, since in the first one the structure is defined only once, while in the second one it's defined at every cast (or so it looks like to me, that's why i'm asking)

Comment: You're correct that the structure is redefined every time, but that happens at compile time, not runtime.  At runtime, the structure's "fields" are just hard-coded (by the compiler) offsets from its starting address.

Comment: I guess I should add that this answer is technically platform-specific and not guaranteed by the C standard — in principle, you might be using a C interpreter that parses the source code at runtime, in which case the duplicate structure definitions might take additional work.  But in practice, everyone compiles C to machine code, and the compiler resolves structure fields to fixed offsets.